# How to call a function before the qwidget is show()n

Tags: c++, qwidget

Is it possible to call a function before a window which inherits from QWidget is shown when one calls `show()`?

I think it may be possible thanks to events interception and some coding workaround (overload & co). Any suggestion?

**EDIT:** This function is to be called only once in the window's life cycle (in other word, a `load` function which is not to be called in the ctor but must be called before `show`)

Comment: To avoid error raising in the ctor. In C++, one should avoid to call function which might throw error in ctors, doesn't it?

Comment: No, throwing exceptions in constructor is perfectly reasonable. In fact, separating initialization code in another method and requires it to be called just after construction is invitation to countless trouble, just like your question demonstrates. If an object's initialization fails, it should not have existed at all.

Comment: So separating member and gui initialization is a bad idea/way of coding?

Comment: Yes. It is bad coding.

Comment: Ok! Might that relate to RAII? I especially coded with MFC so I was surprised that there were no `load` function for windows.

Answer (score 0):

You can reimplement

```cpp
void QWidget::showEvent(QShowEvent * event)
```

in you subclass.